# Is this lesser version of Life Transference balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, wizard, homebrew-review

My ("plain vanilla" dnd 5e) wizard is now near level 8, and I was thinking to equip him with a straightforward *reduced* version of "Life Transference".

The purpose of this is merely as an *emergency maneuver* to prevent the other members of our party (or mainly the cleric) from staying unconscious (or dying) when reduced to 0 HP, for which a 3rd  level spell as "Life Transference" seems to me a bit over-killing (also, given his reduced HP, it can be dangerous for my wizard to *sacrifice* those 4d8 HP in a single round)

This is what I come up with:

> #### Sacrifical Leech
>
> *1st-level necromancy*
> **Casting time:** 1 action
> **Range:** 30 feet
> **Components:** V,S
> **Duration:** Instantaneous
>
> You sacrifice some of your health to mend another creature’s injuries. You take (1d8 + your spellcasting ability modifier)  necrotic damage, which can’t be reduced in any way, and one creature of your choice that you can see within range regains a number of hit points equal to twice the necrotic damage you take.
>
> At Higher Levels:
> When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 1st level or higher, the damage increases by 1d8 for each slot level above 1st.
>
> Spell Lists: Cleric, Wizard

BTW:
the section "At Higher Levels" is not that important to me
so maybe it can be removed altogether.

So my question is: does this sound balanced for the game?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Is the spell balanced isn't the right question to ask. Wizards are not supposed to heal, so this spell is changing what the class can do, that's a big issue.

Comment: @SeriousBri *Life transference* is a wizard spell

Comment: @Jack one at reasonably high level, can't be cast often, doesn't heal much and almost kills the wizard. The op is talking about how it is too risky and wants an easier to cast version but the risk is entirely the point of it.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

### This seems balanced compared to *Life Transference*

*Life transference*, at 3rd level, costs 4d8, and heals for twice that.  Your spell, at 1d8 + spellcasting ability modifier, compares proportionally to that.

It *does* heal for twice what *cure wounds* does, and at a distance, but, of course, it has the disadvantage of the necrotic damage.

### Is it balanced otherwise?

As @Darth_Pseudonym points out in his answer, *life transference* is *supposed* to be dangerous to the wizard.  And it's relatively costly, requiring a 3rd level slot.  By making emergency healing relatively cheap for wizards, they're encroaching on other classes skills.

### Is it balanced within the party?

Bards, clerics, druids, paladins, rangers, and artificers can all cast *cure wounds*.  There are many other ways to heal -- healing potions, for one.  So, maybe within the party it makes more sense for the wizard to let other healing classes do the healing, and stick to what wizards are good at.

### Does the DM think this is balanced?

That's the real question.  You'll have to ask them.

Some DMs might be just fine with it; after all, there are many ways to heal just a few hit points. Lots of classes have *cure wounds*, there are other features such as the paladin's laying on of hands, and there are also healing potions.

Other DMs might think the game has enough healing, and wants that emergency maneuver to cost a 3rd-level slot, plus the risk of significant damage to the wizard.

### But . . . should wizards even heal?

In comments, @SeriousBri points out, "[w]izards are not supposed to heal", and @Joel_Harmon notes that the role of the wizard "does not generally include cheap healing."

Indeed, *life transference* is from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, and in both the *Basic Rules* and the *Player's Handbook*, wizards have no spells which heal others.

So, another consideration for the DM is to what extent they want to allow wizards to do healing, even slightly expensive healing.

Answer (score 28):

The fact that *life transference* drains a dangerous amount of HP from the caster is a feature, not a bug. It's *intentional* that one of the only ways a wizard has to perform healing magic requires a heavy price. Cutting the price down doesn't make for a weaker but still balanced spell; it makes for a role-breaking effect.

Wizards aren't *supposed* to be able to heal very well. There are classes that heal and classes that don't, and a wizard is on the "don't" list. The spell may well be balanced in terms of spell-slot-per-HP, but it's not balanced in terms of the class roles.

In fact, the DMG specifically warns about this; p283 has advice for when you're creating custom spells, and the last bullet point says:

> Make sure the spell fits with the identity of the class. Wizards and sorcerers don't typically have access to healing spells, for example, and adding a healing spell to the wizard class list would step on the cleric's turf.

Frankly, if you want an emergency heal that just restores a handful of HP at the cost of an action to get the cleric off the floor, that's just called a potion. The need is covered without having to invent a new spell to do it.

Comment: This was exactly the kind of answer I was expecting.
The problem with using a healing potion is  that, whenever the party cleric falls unconscious  ("0 HP"), the wizard is likely to be very far from the cleric's body,  and reaching him to administer the potion may be risky to say the least. 
All this given maybe  the best choice for the wizard could be to send his owl familiar with a salve of  Restorative Ointment (in theory it works either by ingestion or by skin contact) - it costs some gold, but no spell slot.

Comment: What about Mage hand to deliver the potion?

Comment: Mage hand is a viable option too, but its speed is 1/2 of owl's speed and it disappears if it is more than 30 feet from the wizard. The owl is generally faster and has the flyby feat (but I am fully aware that it may be easily *killed* anyway)

Comment: @sigmud: 8th level is high enough that your wizard should have access to *Dimension Door*. At lower levels, there is *Misty Step* (but range is a problem, as you identify). Either way, the whole point of the game is to confront players with problems and challenge then to find solutions, not to hand them solutions on a silver platter.

Comment: @sigmud ... or just multiclass. :) (if allowed at your table)

Comment: "Reaching him to administer the potion may be risky to say the least" - good?  The game is functioning as intended and forcing you to make some hard decisions. That's *also* a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Or be a Mark of Healing halfling to get access to healing spells as a Wizard, and break all roles =D in my table, we have a level 20 Mark of Healing wizard, and the Spell Mastery for the 1st level spell is Healing Word. Free BA healing! (at the cost of being unable to cast leveled spells with action or reaction that turn [not round])